# BBPress private topics by default

Tags: bbpress, members

I'm using the BBPress plugin for WordPress and also the Members plugin.  Does anyone know of an easy way to make Topics for members only by default?  I know the Gravity Forms forum does this but I do not see an obvious way to go about it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what do yo mean by make "make Topics for members only by default?" please explain your problem.

Comment: I want the topics to be only viewable by members of the site, not to the public

Answer (score 2):

bbpress forums can be marked public (accessible to all)  private(filters private forums from view when the user does not have appropriate role) and hidden (Make selected forums completely hidden except to certain members or roles)  which can solve your problem. Mark a forum private or hidden according to your requirement and using your members plugin giver respective user roles permissions to view and participate in these forums.

Comment: The forums have the ability to be private, but not the topics.  I did a test and even with the forum as private, when logged out I can access the URL for individual topics.  You would think it would as simple as that setting, but maybe it's a bug in bbpress?